# Show Local Bone Orientation Over Global

Tags: rigging, axis

I'm new to blender, go easy! I want to display the local bone orientation, but all I see is the origin displaying x/y/z instead of per bone. Cant figure this out for the life of me!?
[image: Current Issue]

Comment: Posted my question after at least 30 minutes of looking around to find the answer just after I post. You must enable "Axes" display under the "Object Constraint Properties" tab instead of "Object Properties" tab in the Properties panel.

Comment: it's in the Object Data properties panel > Viewport Display > Axes, to be exact